# Why is my Vue JS Nuxt lazy loaded component bundled in app.js, not loaded separately?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, nuxt.js, lazy-loading

I've just started using Nuxt but have used VueJS for a while. For a test, I've tried lazy loading the tutorial component that is created with the create-nuxt-app command. (I've tried my own component too but went back to a fresh app to try and get Lazy Loading to work). Unfortunately, the component is not lazy loaded.

The index page in my new app is very simple. It has a button to show the tutorial component that is named "LazyTutorial" to indicate lazy loading. The component uses v-if to hide it until the button is clicked.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <button @click="start">
      Show tutorial
    </button>
    <LazyTutorial v-if="showTutorial"></LazyTutorial>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  data () {
    return {
      showTutorial: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    start () {
      this.showTutorial = true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

The Tutorial component is unchanged from the original.

According to what I've seen (eg: [Debbie O'Brien's Nuxt Auto Components and Lazy Loading](https://explorers.netlify.com/learn/get-started-with-nuxt/nuxt-auto-components-and-lazy-loading)), it's simply a matter of using dynamically loaded components (`components:true` in nuxt.config.js) and the "Lazy" prefix on the component.

The app builds fine and works as expected *from the user perspective* - but the component code is bundled into the app.js file, it's NOT lazy loaded. It doesn't appear in the network tab when I click the button because it's already in the app file.

I'm running locally using `npm run dev`.

**Have I missed some configuration settings? What's wrong here?**

Here's my dependency list for version numbers:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
```

Running on Windows 10 (if relevant)

Comment: It running on Windows 10 probably have no impact. Also, it seems like it's not working when running in `dev` mode, did you tried to `yarn generate` / `yarn build` then `yarn start` it to see if it works then? Seems legit to not have to load it again and again. Working on my side (when bundled for production).

Comment: @kissu - that's it. It seems that it's just the dev build that isn't working. I ran `npm run build` and `npm run start` and it lazy loads correctly. I haven't seen anything about this not working in dev though?

Comment: Not sure about dev, but at the end of the day, Webpack is maybe a bit slow already that it doesn't want to trigger HMR + lazy loading every time you save your file, which is not the worst thing IMO. Nuxt3 is using Vite, and importing it properly even during dev (can be seen in the network tab), since it's RC is programmed for the 7th April, you may maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt2 uses Webpack4 and (probably for performance reasons) it is not showing the lazy loading of the `.vue` components during development.

That being said, when you bundle your project (`npm run build && npm run start` in your case), it is working perfectly fine (can be seen in the Network tab of the devtools).

---

As a side note, a Nuxt3 variant would be

```html
<template>
  <button @click="shownComponent = !shownComponent">toggle me please</button>
  <lazy-test v-if="shownComponent" />
</template>

<script setup>
const shownComponent = ref(false)
</script>
```

And importing it properly even during development

[image]

This comes probably from the fact that Vite is better at this, or maybe have more explicit HMR settings. Anyway, the RC release is [really close](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3447#discussioncomment-2476704) so I would recommend maybe checking [nuxtjs3](/questions/tagged/nuxtjs3). Especially if you're a heavy user of TS.

Otherwise, you would need to find and see how to configure Webpack's HMR settings (disclaimer: I'm not sure if it's feasible).

Comment: This is great information and it's working for me after running build/start. However, I would like to know if it SHOULD work in dev. Nothing I've seen in documentation or training material has suggested it wouldn't work.

Comment: @mmarlow probably because it doesn't matter if it works in dev. What's interesting is if it works in production. So, if your code is fine when shipped in production, why should you bother thinking about dev? Lazy-load it and live your life. Otherwise, some deep dive into the HMR + webpack configuration will be required. Not sure if it's worth the hassle.

Comment: So I can confirm in Nuxt 3 this doesn't work, meaning my Dev mode & Prod builds have the same issue / there's no difference. There must be a better way to dynamically import the component when & as needed, including all related assets to that specific component (HTML, JS, CSS)

Comment: ps: I have also found that the Nuxt "LazyComponentName" method doesn't really work well at all. I've renamed all my components & found no difference in my Browser tests & also when I look at the Elements inspect I can see all components are loaded upfront / i.e. there is no Lazy loading

Comment: @Brett just double-checked and it works perfectly fine (please do open a new question if you want to go deeper). As for the performance, it's not trivial to test, and lazy-loading everything is not a magic solution either. Here is a video talking a bit more about the subject: https://youtu.be/YbAQC1yetUM